# WPF spellcheck richtextbox retry

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently embedding WPF into my C# project for it to spell check, but I've stumbled onto quite an odd issue.

As you can see, I have an empty `RichTextBox`

I embedded a WPF rich text box to C# like this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox();

elementHost1.Child = richTextBox1;
omschrijving.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
```

Now here is where the odd part begins:

**[Working]** Example 1: (here I load an `.rtf` file into my textbox)

```
TextRange range = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
FileStream stream = new FileStream("file_example.rtf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
range.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
stream.Close();
```

**[Not working]** Example 2: (here I load a `.txt` file into my textbox)

```
TextRange range = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
FileStream stream = new FileStream("file_example.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
range.Load(stream, DataFormats.Text);
stream.Close();
```

**[Not working]** Example 3: (here I don't load a file, because I don't need to, instead I just pass the string)

```
new System.Windows.Documents.TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text = omschrijving_temp;
```

**[Not working]** Example 4: (here I don't load a file, because I don't need to, instead I just append the string)

```
omschrijving.AppendText(omschrijving_temp);
```

**Example 1** loads the text into the `RichTextBox`, and then shows red dots on the text (spelling errors).

**Example 2** loads the text into the `RichTextBox`, and then ignores the spelling check.

**Example 3** loads the text into the `RichTextBox`, and then ignores the spelling check.

**Example 4** loads the text into the `RichTextBox`, and then ignores the spelling check.

In all the examples above, when I type in the `RichTextBox` (after the text is appended), the spelling check works perfectly,
but it ignores the spelling check for the automatically added text.

When appending text to the `RichTextBox` it seems to work only when it's in a `.RTF` (richtext) format; otherwise it just ignores the spelling check.

Is there any fix, is this a bug? or?

Comment: What is ``omschrijving``?  Something like `Application`? Do you mean `System`?